# What is the best method of scanning nearby locations?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, google-play-services

Quick note, I am new to programming Android applications so feel free to say I'm going about this the entirely wrong way or even to explain things to me like I'm an idiot.

My application is very location dependent. I am using the Google Play Location Services to provide the users current location. Users can store locations in their device which I store using a hashmap. In order to make it more convenient I am trying to make it so the user only has to be within a range of that stored location. My current method to create this range is to essentially use a for loop to scan the user's current location to see if it is in the hashmap.

```
 public String scan(Location local) {
    String fLoc = "";
    List<String> pLoc = new ArrayList<String>();
    String loc = "";
    double lat = local.getLatitude();
    double lon = local.getLongitude();
    lat = (double) Math.round(lat * decimal) / decimal;
    lon = (double) Math.round(lon * decimal) / decimal;
    for (double x = -8; x < 9; x++) {
        double tlat = lat;
        double tlon = lon;
        tlat = tlat + (x / decimal);
        tlat = (double) Math.round(tlat * decimal) / decimal;
        for (double y = -8; y < 9; y++) {
            tlon = lon;
            tlon = tlon + (y / decimal);
            tlon = (double) Math.round(tlon * decimal) / decimal;
            loc = ("Latitude: " + tlat + "   Longitude: " + tlon);
            if (locMap.containsKey(loc)) {
                pLoc.add(loc);
            }

        }
    }
    if (pLoc.isEmpty()) {
        lat = local.getLatitude();
        lon = local.getLongitude();
        lat = (double) Math.round(lat * decimal) / decimal;
        lon = (double) Math.round(lon * decimal) / decimal;
        loc = ("Latitude: " + lat + "   Longitude: " + lon);
        fLoc = loc;
    } else if (pLoc.size() == 1) {
        fLoc = (String) pLoc.toArray()[0];
    } else {
        Double diff = 0.0;
        Double tdiff = 10.0;
        for (String l : pLoc) {
            diff = 10.0;
            String[] parts = l.split(" ");
            double dlat = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]) - lat;
            if (dlat < 0) {
                dlat = dlat * -1;
            }
            double dlon = Double.parseDouble(parts[5]) - lon;
            if (dlon < 0) {
                dlon = dlon * -1;
            }
            diff = dlon + dlat;

            if (diff < tdiff) {
                tdiff = diff;
                fLoc = l;
            }
        }

    }
    return fLoc;
}
```

If no location is close, the user's current location is returned. I feel this is a crude method that is wasteful. What is a better way to find nearby locations? Maybe a for loop through saved location to see if the difference between it and the nearby location is small enough, but this could get costly when the user starts save lots of locations.

Any suggestions?

PS Any tips on adding accurate elevation without barometers?